# Json parsing error in android Malformed Json

Tags: android, json

I can parse the following response successfully

```
    {
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "errorCode": "0000",
    "errorMessage": "",
    "resultType": " appointments   ",
    "result": [
        {
            "appointmentTime": {
                "date": 26,
                "day": 3,
                "hours": 5,
                "minutes": 30,
                "month": 1,
                "nanos": 0,
                "seconds": 0,
                "time": 1393372800000,
                "timezoneOffset": -330,
                "year": 114
            },
            "createdOn": {
                "date": 26,
                "day": 3,
                "hours": 15,
                "minutes": 31,
                "month": 1,
                "nanos": 0,
                "seconds": 38,
                "time": 1393408898000,
                "timezoneOffset": -330,
                "year": 114
            },
            "cretedById": 1,
            "customer": {
                "createdOn": {
                    "date": 30,
                    "day": 4,
                    "hours": 14,
                    "minutes": 40,
                    "month": 0,
                    "nanos": 0,
                    "seconds": 49,
                    "time": 1391073049000,
                    "timezoneOffset": -330,
                    "year": 114
                },
                "customerAddress1": "jsfhdj",
                "customerAddress2": "sdaf",
                "customerAddress3": "jsfhdj",
                "customerCity": "sdfasdf",
                "customerCountry": "fdasfa",
                "customerEmail1": "54",
                "customerEmail2": "dfjjfsjf",
                "customerEmail3": "sdjflj",
                "customerFax1": "54564",
                "customerFax2": "545656",
                "customerLocation": "amol",
                "customerName": "amoltest",
                "customerPhone1": "4654654",
                "customerPhone2": "5456",
                "customerPhone3": "5456",
                "customerPrintas": "amol",
                "customerState": "fasdfasdf",
                "customerType": 0,
                "customerWebsiteUrl1": "sdfj",
                "customerWebsiteUrl2": "jfklsj",
                "customerZipcode": "1345",
                "id": 6,
                "industry": "jshfd",
                "isHeadOffice": true,
                "lasknownLangitude": 78.640137,
                "lasknownLatitude": 17.14079,
                "territory": "sjdfh"
            },
            "id": 3,
            "outcomeId": 6,
            "purposeId": 6,
            "userId": 6
        },
        {
            "appointmentTime": {
                "date": 26,
                "day": 3,
                "hours": 5,
                "minutes": 30,
                "month": 1,
                "nanos": 0,
                "seconds": 0,
                "time": 1393372800000,
                "timezoneOffset": -330,
                "year": 114
            },
            "createdOn": {
                "date": 27,
                "day": 4,
                "hours": 11,
                "minutes": 2,
                "month": 1,
                "nanos": 0,
                "seconds": 4,
                "time": 1393479124000,
                "timezoneOffset": -330,
                "year": 114
            },
            "cretedById": 0,
            "customer": {
                "createdOn": {
                    "date": 30,
                    "day": 4,
                    "hours": 14,
                    "minutes": 40,
                    "month": 0,
                    "nanos": 0,
                    "seconds": 49,
                    "time": 1391073049000,
                    "timezoneOffset": -330,
                    "year": 114
                },
                "customerAddress1": "jsfhdj",
                "customerAddress2": "sdaf",
                "customerAddress3": "jsfhdj",
                "customerCity": "sdfasdf",
                "customerCountry": "fdasfa",
                "customerEmail1": "54",
                "customerEmail2": "dfjjfsjf",
                "customerEmail3": "sdjflj",
                "customerFax1": "54564",
                "customerFax2": "545656",
                "customerLocation": "amol",
                "customerName": "amoltest",
                "customerPhone1": "4654654",
                "customerPhone2": "5456",
                "customerPhone3": "5456",
                "customerPrintas": "amol",
                "customerState": "fasdfasdf",
                "customerType": 0,
                "customerWebsiteUrl1": "sdfj",
                "customerWebsiteUrl2": "jfklsj",
                "customerZipcode": "1345",
                "id": 6,
                "industry": "jshfd",
                "isHeadOffice": true,
                "lasknownLangitude": 78.640137,
                "lasknownLatitude": 17.14079,
                "territory": "sjdfh"
            },
            "id": 7,
            "outcomeId": 5,
            "purposeId": 5,
            "userId": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I try to parse this response i get MalformedJsonException

```
 {
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "errorCode": "0000",
    "errorMessage": "",
    "resultType": " appointments   ",
    "result": [
        {
            "appointmentTime": {
                "date": 26,
                "day": 3,
                "hours": 9,
                "minutes": 29,
                "month": 2,
                "nanos": 0,
                "seconds": 39,
                "time": 1395826179000,
                "timezoneOffset": 0,
                "year": 114
            },
            "createdOn": {
                "date": 26,
                "day": 3,
                "hours": 9,
                "minutes": 29,
                "month": 2,
                "nanos": 0,
                "seconds": 39,
                "time": 1395826179000,
                "timezoneOffset": 0,
                "year": 114
            },
            "cretedById": 3,
            "customer": {
                "createdOn": {
                    "date": 22,
                    "day": 6,
                    "hours": 10,
                    "minutes": 1,
                    "month": 2,
                    "nanos": 0,
                    "seconds": 20,
                    "time": 1395482480000,
                    "timezoneOffset": 0,
                    "year": 114
                },
                "customerAddress1": "nani peth",
                "customerAddress2": "LBS road",
                "customerAddress3": "pune",
                "customerCity": "pune",
                "customerCountry": "India",
                "customerEmail1": "abc@ac.in",
                "customerEmail2": "ac@ab.in",
                "customerEmail3": "as@wd.in",
                "customerFax1": "2345",
                "customerFax2": "3214",
                "customerLocation": "Pune",
                "customerName": "ABC consultancy",
                "customerPhone1": "234567",
                "customerPhone2": "34567677887",
                "customerPhone3": "3445566",
                "customerPrintas": "ABC consultancy",
                "customerState": "maharashtra",
                "customerType": 0,
                "customerWebsiteUrl1": "www.abc.in",
                "customerWebsiteUrl2": "www.abc.com",
                "customerZipcode": "411030",
                "id": 1,
                "industry": "finance",
                "isHeadOffice": true,
                "lasknownLangitude": 72.846268,
                "lasknownLatitude": 19.117189,
                "territory": "pune"
            },
            "id": 1,
            "outcomeId": 1,
            "purposeId": 1,
            "userId": 2
        },
        {
            "appointmentTime": {
                "date": 26,
                "day": 3,
                "hours": 9,
                "minutes": 29,
                "month": 2,
                "nanos": 0,
                "seconds": 54,
                "time": 1395826194000,
                "timezoneOffset": 0,
                "year": 114
            },
            "createdOn": {
                "date": 26,
                "day": 3,
                "hours": 9,
                "minutes": 29,
                "month": 2,
                "nanos": 0,
                "seconds": 54,
                "time": 1395826194000,
                "timezoneOffset": 0,
                "year": 114
            },
            "cretedById": 3,
            "customer": {
                "createdOn": {
                    "date": 22,
                    "day": 6,
                    "hours": 10,
                    "minutes": 1,
                    "month": 2,
                    "nanos": 0,
                    "seconds": 20,
                    "time": 1395482480000,
                    "timezoneOffset": 0,
                    "year": 114
                },
                "customerAddress1": "nani peth",
                "customerAddress2": "LBS road",
                "customerAddress3": "pune",
                "customerCity": "pune",
                "customerCountry": "India",
                "customerEmail1": "abc@ac.in",
                "customerEmail2": "ac@ab.in",
                "customerEmail3": "as@wd.in",
                "customerFax1": "2345",
                "customerFax2": "3214",
                "customerLocation": "Pune",
                "customerName": "ABC consultancy",
                "customerPhone1": "234567",
                "customerPhone2": "34567677887",
                "customerPhone3": "3445566",
                "customerPrintas": "ABC consultancy",
                "customerState": "maharashtra",
                "customerType": 0,
                "customerWebsiteUrl1": "www.abc.in",
                "customerWebsiteUrl2": "www.abc.com",
                "customerZipcode": "411030",
                "id": 1,
                "industry": "finance",
                "isHeadOffice": true,
                "lasknownLangitude": 72.846268,
                "lasknownLatitude": 19.117189,
                "territory": "pune"
            },
            "id": 2,
            "outcomeId": 1,
            "purposeId": 1,
            "userId": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: see you JSON code in this http://json.parser.online.fr/ if show perfect than you can parse

Comment: can you please put your code, so i can be help you..